# Is there a way to get the logs for all transactions in a block?

Tags: parity, erc-20, logs, monitoring

I am building a system that monitors ERC20 token deposits to a large number of ethereum addresses (1-4 million). While I have not tried, I do not think that the parity clients would be able to support such a large amount of filters. I intend to build a customised data structure in order to achieve this task. **Therefore, I would like to acquire the logs of all transactions in a block. Is there a way to do so?**

This question is related to [How to programmatically detect and accept ETH and ERC20 deposits](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27805/how-to-programmatically-detect-and-accept-eth-and-erc20-deposits)

However, answers to the above post have not adequately addressed my concern about scalability.

---

What I have tried:

I am currently scanning the whole block for transaction hashes and then using `eth_getTransactionReceipt` to acquire the logs for each transaction. The pseudocode is as follows:

```
@parallel
for block in all blocks:
  all_tx = get_all_txs(block);
  for tx in all_tx:
    save_in_db(eth_getTransactionReceipt(tx).getlogs())
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to retrieve the logs, perhaps retrieving all logs at once?

Answer (score 1):

See eth_getLogs:
https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-eth-module#eth_getlogs

There you have possibility to filter only logs from ERC20 using topics.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `eth_getLogs` method to pull logs from blocks.

If you want to get all of the logs emitted by all of the transactions in a block, you can run the `eth_getLogs`, leaving only the block (fromBlock and toBlock) you need in the filter.

Here is an example in cURL:

```sh
curl 'YOUR_NODE_ENDPOINT' \
--header 'accept: application/json' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "method": "eth_getLogs",
  "params": [
    {
      "fromBlock": "latest",
      "toBlock": "latest"
    }
  ],
  "id": 1,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}'
```

This setup will retrieve all of the logs emitted in the specified block.

You can see more examples on the [Chainstack docs | eth_getLogs](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-getlogs), or learn more about logs in general reading [Tracking some Bored Apes: The Ethereum event logs tutorial](https://docs.chainstack.com/docs/tracking-some-bored-apes-the-ethereum-event-logs-tutorial)