# How to test if contract is receiving ETH

Tags: solidity, testing, unittesting

I'm desperately trying to find an answer as to how I can accurately test my smart contract balances, as not only can I not get the test to return the correct balance number, but I also am not seeing any test ether leaving my Hardhat test account either.

Relevant code is below, what am I doing wrong??? I've looked everywhere for a concrete answer but I can't seem to find one. The idea is just a simple pool contract that is only accepting deposits (in ETH, important) at this point, and then should accurately state that it has the user's deposited amount of funds.

Am I referencing the amount wrong? Is it a conversion issue between the two? Anyone know what gives on this? I feel like this action is super simple so I must be on the wrong page about something, but both balances currently return zero.

Contract:

```
contract DepositPool {

  mapping(address => uint256) public userBalance;

  function makeDeposit(
        uint256 _amount,
        address _from
      ) public payable {
          require(_amount > 0, "Must input amount to deposit");

          _amount = msg.value;
          _from = msg.sender;

        userBalance[msg.sender] += msg.value;

        console.log("User balance: ", userBalance[msg.sender]);
        console.log("Contract balance: ", address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
describe('DepositPool', function () {
    it('Should accept deposits and have correct balances', async function () {

        const Pool = await ethers.getContractFactory('DepositPool');
        const pool = await Pool.deploy();
        await pool.deployed();

        const [user] = await ethers.getSigners();

        const makeADeposit = await pool.connect(user).makeDeposit(20, user.address);

        await makeABet.wait();
        console.log(makeABet);
        console.log(await pool.getPoolBalance().toString());

        assert.equal(20, 20, 'Pool balance should equal 20');
    });
```

**using Hardhat's console.log import by the way if anyone is wondering why those log statements are in there

THANK YOU!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to programmatically detect and accept ETH and ERC20 deposits](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27805/how-to-programmatically-detect-and-accept-eth-and-erc20-deposits)

Answer (score 1):

When you send ETH, the `value` is the amount in Wei, from the `msg.sender`, so no need to pass `amount` and `from`.

You can try this

```
contract DepositPool {

  mapping(address => uint256) public userBalance;

  function makeDeposit() public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0, "Must input amount to deposit");

        userBalance[msg.sender] += msg.value;

        console.log("User balance: ", userBalance[msg.sender]);
        console.log("Contract balance: ", address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

When you test, just send ETH use `from` and `value`

```js
describe('DepositPool', function () {
    it('Should accept deposits and have correct balances', async function () {

        const Pool = await ethers.getContractFactory('DepositPool');
        const pool = await Pool.deploy();
        await pool.deployed();

        const [user] = await ethers.getSigners();

        const makeADeposit = await pool.connect(user).makeDeposit({from: user.address, value: 20});

        await makeABet.wait();
        console.log(makeABet);
        console.log(await pool.getPoolBalance().toString());

        assert.equal(20, 20, 'Pool balance should equal 20');
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The above does make sense to me and that is how I initially had it setup, however my test always errors out whenever I remove the amount variable in the contract and tells me it's an invalid BigNumber value for the test argument. Even on Remix I can't get the correct balances to return, I feel like this is so simple but I just have zero idea as to why the balances won't update at all