# How to send ether from smart contract to a particular address

Tags: transfer, msg.sender

I initially transferred some ether into the smart contract when deployed and in one of the function I should be transferring ether to the address of the msg.sender. Help me out if you can!

Comment: Could you share your code, that way it will be easier for us to help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to programmatically detect and accept ETH and ERC20 deposits](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27805/how-to-programmatically-detect-and-accept-eth-and-erc20-deposits)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of a function by which someone can get a specific amount of **wei** from a contract contaning this function.

I tried to keep it as simple as possible. Therefore it is unsafe to use, as this function can be called by **anyone** to withdraw ETH from the contract. Please use it only for learning purposes and don't implement it on any production contracts.

```
function withdraw(uint amount) public {

    (bool sent, ) = msg.sender.call{value: amount}("");
    require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");

  
}
```