# erc20 transfer function not working

Tags: solidity, transfer

i am developing a locking smart-contract where user can add token address, amount and lock time. i imported erc20 standard from openzeplin but when i transfer erc20 tokens to my smartcontract is saying not a ethereum address( on ropston). i also try on remix its not working.

here is the code

```
  pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";

contract lock  {
    address public owner;
    
   struct Lock{
       address token;
       uint amount;
       uint endtime;

   }
    
 
 constructor() {
     owner= msg.sender;
    }

   mapping(address => Lock) public tokenLock;

    function locker( address _token, uint256 _amount, uint _time) public{
        
        tokenLock[msg.sender]= Lock(_token, _amount, _time);
        IERC20(_token).transfer( address(this),_amount);
       }


    
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to programmatically detect and accept ETH and ERC20 deposits](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27805/how-to-programmatically-detect-and-accept-eth-and-erc20-deposits)

Answer (score 1):

When a user must to deposit an amount of tokens in your smart contract, you must to use `transferFrom()` function. This operation, allow user to give permission to access in his wallet and deposit tokens amount without exceed the allowance. In your case, you must to change your smart contract in this way:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";

contract lock  {
    address public owner;
    
    struct Lock{
        address token;
        uint amount;
        uint endtime;
    }
    
    constructor() {
        owner= msg.sender;
    }

    mapping(address => Lock) public tokenLock;

    function locker(address _token, uint256 _amount, uint _time) public {    
        tokenLock[msg.sender]= Lock(_token, _amount, _time);
        IERC20(_token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this),_amount);
    }

    function getBalanceSmartContract(address _token) external view returns(uint) {
        return IERC20(_token).balanceOf(address(this));
    }
    
}
```

And before a user call `locker()` function, he must to approve your smart contract to deposit his tokens into it. For this operation, user'll call `approve()` function that exists into ERC20 Token smart contract and must to pass it following values:

- spender: your smart contract address;
- amount: how many tokens spender can handle.

And only then a user can call your `locker()` function.