# execution reverted: "ERC20: insufficient allowance" on transfer method (not transferFrom)

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, transfer

I'm developing a Smart Contract that transfer tokens that are owned by the Smart Contract itself. The function to do that is pretty simple:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.1;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract TransferTokens {

    IERC20 token;

    constructor(){
        token = IERC20(0x...);
    }

    function sendTokens(address receiver, uint256 amount) external {
        token.transfer(receiver, amount);
    }
}
```

And I'm getting:
execution reverted: **ERC20: insufficient allowance**

I have deployed my own token, which is an [Openzeppelin ERC20](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol) contract.
That revocation happens in _spendAllowance function, which is invoked in transferFrom function, not in transfer function.

How can it be possible to get an error (from transferFrom function) that should not be thrown in my function (transfer function)?

How could I make my contract able to send the received ERC20 tokens, after a function execution?

Comment: You need to approve the funds before doing the transfer

Comment: The funds are in the balance of the Smart Contract

Comment: it doesn't matter, you need to approve the receiver before transferring the token

Comment: I don't get your point: Who should approve the Smart Contract's address? The Smart Contract is trying to transfer its own tokens (on its balance).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to programmatically detect and accept ETH and ERC20 deposits](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27805/how-to-programmatically-detect-and-accept-eth-and-erc20-deposits)

Comment: No, sorry. I want to make my contract able to send the received ERC20 tokens, after a function execution. And I do not understand why I received an error from transferFrom function, when I using transfer function.

Comment: @AlexAcc The code supplied works as expected. It could be that you were using an old version that called transferFrom? Or you are using an ERC20 token that has a different implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked balanceOf() with address of smart contract? Does it show any balance?
Also, I don't understand why are you writing

```
IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
```

You have already instantiatiated token in constructor. And what 'tokenAddress' are you passing?

Comment: Yes sure, the contract had the received balance. And you are right, that line of code  was redundant, already instantiated.